# How to upload files and get files in uploads files in laravel5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am not able to upload files the the uploads folder. I am not using public folder, I removed the public files and moved in root directors my folders sturucture for Laravel.

```
app
bootstrap
config
css
database
fonts
images
storage
tests
vendor
uploads
.env
.htaccess
index
```

My AashishController.php

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Input;
use Mail;

class AashishController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{

return view('in');  

}
public function contact()
{
    return view('contact'); 
}
public function postcontact()
{
     $name = \Input::get('name');
     $email = \Input::get('email');
     $phone = \Input::get('phone');
     $message1 = \Input::get('message');
     $file1 = Input::file('file1');

     $userr=$file1;

    //Create directory if it does not exist
    if(!is_dir("uploads/".$userr."/")) {
        mkdir("uploads/".$userr."/");
    }

    // Move the uploaded file
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/".$userr."/". $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    $to ="email@example.com";
    $subject = "hi";
    $mail_body = '<html>
        <body bgcolor="#573A28" topmargin="25">
        Put HTML content here with variables from PHP if you like
        Variable display Example: 
        </body>
    </html>';
    $headers  = "From:email@example.com";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html";
    mail($to, $subject, $mail_body, $headers);
    return view('test')->with('name', $name);
}
}
```

How to get the file from that directory and pass it to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting any errors ?

You may forgot the give write permission with chmod 777 to uploads folder.

edit: Remove the last slash from mkdir path.

And make sure `$userr` variable contains a valid value with `dd($userr);`

Oh ok i see now.

1- You are trying to send an object instead of sending a string to mkdir function.

2- And even i assume that you are trying to send filename to mkdir why do you need to create a folder named with that filename ? Just use timestamp or some random value with similar to rand(100,999) for creating subfolder.

3- And your $userr contains an object like this:

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)[9]
  private 'test' => boolean false
  private 'originalName' => string 'test.jpg' (length=22)
  private 'mimeType' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
  private 'size' => int 667220
  private 'error' => int 0
```

so there is no point to use it as an object or even declaring it. Use just Input::file('file1') instead.

```
public function postcontact()
{
     $name = \Input::get('name');
     $email = \Input::get('email');
     $phone = \Input::get('phone');
     $message1 = \Input::get('message');
     $file1 = Input::file('file1');


    $timestamp = time();
    //Create directory if it does not exist
    if(!is_dir("uploads/".$timestamp)) {
        mkdir("uploads/".$timestamp);
    }

$sitepath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

        // Move the uploaded file
Input::file('file1')->move($sitepath.'/uploads/'.$timestamp.'/', Input::file('file1')->getClientOriginalName());

    $to ="email@example.com";
    $subject = "hi";
    $mail_body = '<html>
        <body bgcolor="#573A28" topmargin="25">
        Put HTML content here with variables from PHP if you like
        Variable display Example: 
        </body>
    </html>';
    $headers  = "From:email@example.com";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html";
    mail($to, $subject, $mail_body, $headers);
    return view('test')->with('name', $name);
}
```

and for accessing path of folder in your view, i'm always preferring use this style:

```
$data['name'] = $name;
$data['filepath'] = "uploads/".$timestamp."/".Input::file('file1')->getClientOriginalName();
return view('test',$data);
```

in your view you can access those variables with blade template engine::

```
name {{ $name }} <br />
filepath {{ $filepath }} <br />
```

or by using raw php variables:

```
name <?php echo $name; ?> <br />
filepath <?php echo $filepath; ?> <br />
```

Comment: can you paste full controller

Comment: but it uploading  a file to uploads folder in controller  folder how can i pass the path  to view

Comment: thanks you but within upload folder i want to created dynamic folder which we  posted name field   and pass the file to it is it possible?

Comment: as i stated in my answer before, using file name for creating folder is not a proper way because filename can contain many invalid chars. but you can use a random number or timestamp for creating it.

Comment: @demodemo added how to create folder with timestamp though.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not sending files with the form, your form should be :

```
{{ Form::open(["url"=>"/someurl", "files"=>true,])}
```

paste your view which is posting data

And you should check the file type before moving them into a upload folder.

instead of

```
$sitepath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

use

```
$sitepath = public_path();
```

Comment: what is the advantage of using public path instead of document root ?

Comment: why do you want to use core stuff when you are using a framework